# Some Clarifications about Electricity

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

1. In the diagram below (ignoring the text), does the $V$ mean that there is some electric field outside of this system which results in a potential difference of $V$ between $a$ and $b$ or does it mean that the potential difference in the capacitor is $V$?

[image]

2. If the answer to the first is the former, how does a battery create a potential difference with only a current?
3. How does charging a capacitor work in the electrostatic situation?
4. When there is two capacitors in a series, why must the they both have the same charge? My book explains that, assuming that the two capacitors is aligned vertically, the lower plate of the top capacitor is connected to the higher plate of the bottom capacitor so it must equal 0 because these plates aren't connected to anything else. This makes no sense to me because charging requires transferring charge, but it seems to be that these two plates are not allowed to transfer charge.

Comment: No.  Nothing outside of the system.  It means there is a voltage difference between point "a" and point "b" which is due to the charge built up across the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram is not well drawn. The charges reside on the other side of each plate.  Thus as a reasonable approximation the E-field only resides between the plates.
When a battery is connected across the capacitor charges flow and charge the capacitor until the voltage across the plates of the capacitor is equal to the voltage of the battery.
When you connect two capacitors in series you join a plate of one capacitor with a wire to a plate on the other capacitor.  Those two plates are electrically isolated from the rest of the circuit by the insulators which are between the plates.  So those two plates had net charge on them and since no charge can enter or leave they will stay with no net charge.  So if one plate has charge $+Q$ on it the other plate must have a charge of $-Q$ on it.

Comment: Why is it that charge only flows across the plates when you attach a battery?

Comment: If the capacitor is uncharged there is no separation of charges on rage plates. When a capacitor is charged there is separation of charge.  Connecting a battery to an uncharged capacitor leads to a separation of charge due to a current (movement of charge) flowing in the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential difference due to an electric field that is (to a good approximation) contained only between the plates.

The battery builds up this potential difference by driving a current. Because the capacitor does not allow charge to flow through it, as current flows, one plate is left with a deficit of electrons and the other with a surplus of electrons, which is seen as a positive and negative charge, respectively. As this charge builds up, the battery has to do work to push more like charges into energetically unfavorable regions, and it is this energy that builds up the potential between the plates.

When two capacitors are in series, the bottom plate of one and the top plate of another are connected electrically. Any electrons on one can only flow to the other. So although charge can move from one to the other, the deficit of electrons on one (seen as a positive charge on one) must be equal to the surplus of electrons on the other (seen as an equal negative charge).